# Visual Studio Community Won't Load Default Files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-community

I'm trying to learn C++ and when I opened a new win32 console project it just gave me an empty project when it should have gave gave me like stdafx.h or the name.cpp file. Any way to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure what version of Visual Studio you're using, but when I go to create a Win32 console project, I'm presented with a wizard that lets me configure the project before it's created.  One of the checkboxes says "Empty Project".

Comment: I don't check the box that says "Empty Project"

Answer (score 1):

Did you try updating your workloads? After installing VS, if you didn't choose the right workloads to load certain types of projects such as Win32 console projects, go into your programs folder from the control panel and right click on Visual Studio. Choose 'change', not 'uninstall'. The page you are given is your workloads. Read them and decide which one supports that type of program. Check that workload, then in the right sidebar you will see custom options. Not all the ones you need may be automatically checked. Make sure any that refer to the build process are checked. Then click to proceed and VS will install the updates.

For Win32 programs, you need to add the workload called "Desktop development with C++" and then on the Installation Details pane on the right check all boxes that mention a "build".